# How to realloc multiple arrays using fgets()

Tags: c, arrays, fgets, realloc

I am trying to read some input using fgets() but I need to store the input in a dynamic array called userNumbers, how am I supposed to get realloc() to work with fgets()? My program breaks when i try to read more than 8 elements(i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 works but 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 does not). Another thing is that I MUST use fgets(). Thanks in advance.

```
size_t capacity = 4;
size_t size = 0;
char* userNumbers = (char*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
char** realNumStr = (char**)malloc(capacity * sizeof(char*));
double* realNumDouble = (double*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(double));
double* realNumDoubleFinal = (double*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(double));
double* realNumDoubleMedian = (double*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(double));

if (userNumbers == NULL || realNumDouble == NULL || realNumDoubleFinal == NULL || realNumStr == NULL)
{
    printf("insufficient Memory");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//User's input
while (fgets(userNumbers, capacity, stream))
{
    size += strlen(userNumbers);

    while (size >= capacity)
    {
        capacity = size * 2;

        char* userNumbers2 = realloc(userNumbers, capacity * sizeof(char)+1);
        char** realNumStr2 = realloc(realNumStr, capacity * sizeof(char*)+1);
        double* realNumDouble2 = realloc(realNumDouble, capacity * sizeof(double));
        double* realNumDoubleFinal2 = realloc(realNumDoubleFinal, capacity * sizeof(double));

        if (userNumbers2 == NULL || realNumDouble2 == NULL || realNumDoubleFinal2 == NULL || realNumStr2 == NULL)
        {
            free(userNumbers);
            free(realNumDouble);
            free(realNumDoubleFinal);
            free(realNumStr);

            printf("insufficient Memory");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        userNumbers = userNumbers2;
        realNumStr = realNumStr2;
        realNumDouble = realNumDouble2;
        realNumDoubleFinal = realNumDoubleFinal2;
    }
```

//...Code continues...
}

//Error thrown: 
HEAP[rstats.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 0000026E15F20000, 0000026E15F298F0 )
stat.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

breakpoint triggered here:
if (!has_cctor)
            _cexit();

Comment: Review `capacity * sizeof(char*)+1`.  Why add 1? Other issues too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You should do this in two separate phases. First read all the input into a string, and just use `realloc()` to grow that string. Then parse the string and add the numbers to the float array, which you grow as you do that.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the response! The problem is that my program needs to read input from multiple lines, and whenever I press enter to jump a line my program enters the while, check if a realloc is needed, check for some typing errors, and then gets back to fgets() asking for more input, and fgets() parses the entire line I typed at once, instead of passing 1 then 2 then 3, it passes 1,2,3. So I can't do this is separate phases.

Comment: @chux I saw some coders doing this in their realloc statement, so i thought it was necessary. The strange thing is that the realloc seems to work once, changing the capacity from 4 to 8, but if a realloc is needed to grow the capacity one more time, it doesn't work

Comment: It is dangerous to `realloc` that way; if the call fails in the middle, you are `free`-ing unallocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

You should read all the input first. Each time you read a line with `fgets()` you need to concatenate it to a buffer containing all the lines. That's the buffer you should be reallocating, you can use a fixed-size buffer for the `fgets()` call.

```
char line[100];
char *numbersStr = NULL;
size_t size = 0;

while (fget(line, sizeof(line), stream) {
    size_t linelen = strlen(line);
    char *newNumbersStr = realloc(numbersStr, size + linelen + 1);
    if (!newNumbersStr) {
        free (numbersStr);
        printf("insufficient Memory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    numbersStr = newNumbersStr;
    strcpy(&numbersStr[size], line);
    size += linelen;
}
```

This loop will end when you get to EOF of `stream`. Then you can parse all the numbers from `numbersStr` into `numbersArray`, which you can grow with `realloc()` in that loop.